# Error 401 when trying to post data with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-oauth, http-status-code-401

I've come across an error 401 when trying to update status from the tweepy API using Python. I've tried following multiple tutorials and blog posts with similar errors, but nothing seems to be working. I suspected that I might have been missing some kind of auth for posting to the api.

Do I need to enable user authentication settings with the twitter dev portal? And if I do what do I input in "Callback URI / Redirect URL" and "Website URL"? Since I'm working out of vscode and jupyter.

Note: It's only when I call api.status_update, that I get "Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized", I can use api.home_timeline to get my timeline, no problem.
Other note: I'm new to Python, so go easy on me..

Here is all of my code.

```
import tweepy
import webbrowser

consumer_key = "my-consumer-key"
consumer_secret = "my-consumer-secret"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, callback="oob")

auth_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
print("AUTH_URL: " + auth_url)
webbrowser.open(auth_url)
verifier = input("Auth PIN:").strip()

auth.get_access_token(verifier)
print("ACCESS_KEY: " + auth.access_token)
print("ACCESS_SECRET: " + auth.access_token_secret)
access_token = auth.access_token
access_token_secret = auth.access_token_secret

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
api.update_status("This message was generated with the Twitter API and Python!")
```

Comment: It sounds like maybe your API keys were only set up with read access, check on the Developer Portal and make sure you have read+write access.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Andy. That is what I thought too. But I don't really know how to get access since I need a callback uri / redirect url and website url in the dev portal, to set that up.

Comment: If you are using the same account as your developer account, or you use twurl or a PIN-based command line method to get tokens, you can safely set those URLs to localhost; they are only needed if you implement login for your site and app.